# How to cancel execution of debounced function in form event?

Tags: lodash, dom-events, formik, debouncing

I have a form with 2 handlers:

```
<form onChange={_.debounce(func, 1000)} onBlur={func} />
```

I used this construction to handle update of the data via websocket connection, and this solution  is just what I need, but in this particular case `func` fires twice on blur, is there any way to cancel execution of `onChange` handler when `onBlur` is being triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found that [lodash .debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) function has two handy methods: `cancel` and `flush` which are just what I've needed.